# designing database relationships

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio, database-design

I'm coding an app that tracks stocks that run on a first day and then track the very next day.

There will be multiple day 1 + day 2 entries for the same ticker. The primary keys are on the ticker.

How do I design the database relationships?

[image: Database diagram]

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & relational & non-relational DB design, querying & DBMSs. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) Dozens are online free in pdf. Also for your particular DBMS & frameworks. (But asking for resources outside SO is off-topic.) Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question about where you are 1st stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to have a `Stock` table that stores general information about the stock and another table `StockPrices` that will store the daily snapshot of the stock.

The primary key for `Stock` will be `Ticker` as it unique identifies a stock and is short/easily understood.

The primary key for `StockPrices` will be `(Ticker,Date)`. The column `Ticker` on this table with have a foreign key relation to the primary key of `Stock`.

Any comparison between two days can be accomplished with a simple query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Stock s
INNER JOIN StockPrices spDay1 ON s.ticker = spDay1.ticker AND spDay1.date = [first day you want to compare to here]
INNER JOIN StockPrices spDay2 ON s.ticker = spDay2.ticker AND spDay2.date = DATEADD(dd, 1, spDay1.date)
```

Comment: @Jon, if he makes the primary key '(Ticker,CloseDate)' there will be no need for additional indexes for that query to be efficient.